TinyMCE initialization error: The chosen schema: "cyclic" did not exist in branches: {}
I am supporting an ASP.Net MVC 4 application. It makes use of TinyMCE (v6.4.1) rich text editor in a number of views. There is one view in which the component fails to initialize, with the following error in the browser console:
Uncaught (in promise)  Error: Errors:  Failed path: (keying-config) The chosen schema: "cyclic" did not exist in branches: {}

Input object: {   "mode": "cyclic",   "selector": ".tox-menubar, .tox-toolbar, .tox-toolbar__primary, .tox-toolbar__overflow--open, .tox-sidebar__overflow--open, .tox-statusbar__path, .tox-statusbar__wordcount, .tox-statusbar__branding a, .tox-statusbar__resize-handle" }
    at theme.min.js:4:21781
    at Object.fold (theme.min.js:4:17055)
    at Xn (theme.min.js:4:21765)
    at Kn (theme.min.js:4:21815)
    at Object.config (theme.min.js:4:42705)
    at v (theme.min.js:4:339082)
    at renderUI (theme.min.js:4:339857)
    at renderUI (theme.min.js:4:395837)
    at tinymce.min.js:4:362627
    at tinymce.min.js:4:362638

Where do I start looking to figure out the root cause of this error? It works in other parts of the app (with identical config - and I know it's identical, because the TinyMCE component is actually defined inside a common shared component that gets loaded in various views), I suspect that there must be something in the DOM of this specific page that is conflicting with the initialization of the TinyMCE component.
Here is how the TinyMCE component is initialized inside the mentioned shared component:
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function () {
        tinymce.init({
            statusbar: false,
             selector: "#MessageBody",
             height: "400",
             width:"672",
             menubar: false,
             branding: false,
             plugins: 'preview importcss searchreplace autolink save directionality code visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media codesample table charmap pagebreak nonbreaking anchor insertdatetime advlist lists wordcount charmap emoticons',
             toolbar1: ' bold italic underline strikethrough | fontfamily fontsize blocks  ',
             toolbar2: 'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent|  numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor removeformat |image link',
             image_advtab: true,
             images_file_types: 'jpg,svg,png,jpeg',
             importcss_append: true,
             image_title: true,
             convert_urls : false,


Ok I was right in my suspicion about there being something in the DOM that is borking the TinyMCE Initialization...I found the needle in the haystack...that view also loads some scripts that is used for reading smart cards...when I remove those scripts, the TinyMCE initialization works.  Gotta love javascript....now to find a way to make the two play nice together.

turns out that the other script that reads smart cards had some horrible code in that resulted in the redefinition of base javascript object methods!!  WHO DOES THAT?!?!?
